# how to resolve Error Paypal code no business

Tags: paypal, module, joomla, payment

on my website, i have a module which create a connection with paypal payment.
I have an error with it. (phoca cart with joomla)
code: NO_BUSINESS

I don't understand my error.

thx

Answer (score 1):

What is the integration type? If it is PayPal Payments Standard, "business" is a required parameter that should correspond to the PayPal account that is to receive the payment

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/